# How can we access object which is not defined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a simple Todo List in ReactJS, while the code is working, I'm having trouble understanding a few pieces of code.

My Application consists of 3 components namely:

1. index.js - The entry point for the application.
2. TodoList.js - Rendering the forms, button and TodoItem.js component
3. TodoItem.js - Actual list which maps over the input text and displays the list.

My TodoList.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TodoItems from "./TodoItems";

class TodoList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: []
    };

    this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
  }

  addItem(e) {
    if (this._inputElement.value !== "") {
      var newItem = {
        text: this._inputElement.value,
        key: Date.now()
      };

      this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
          items: prevState.items.concat(newItem)
        };
      });
    }
    //console.log(this._inputElement.value);
    this._inputElement.value = "";
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="todoListMain">
        <div className="header">
          <form onSubmit={this.addItem}>
            <input
              ref={a => (this._inputElement = a)}
              placeholder="enter task"
            ></input>
            <button type="submit">add</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <TodoItems entries={this.state.items} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TodoList;
```

The TodoItems.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class TodoItems extends Component {
  createTasks(itemmm) {
    return <li key={itemmm.key}>{itemmm.text}</li>;
  }

  render() {
    var todoEntries = this.props.entries;
    var listItems = this.props.entries.map(this.createTasks);
    // console.log(this.props.entries);
    return <ul className="theList">{listItems}</ul>;
  }
}

export default TodoItems;
```

What is the problem?
**1)** I'm having a hard time understanding how `return <li key={itemmm.key}>{itemmm.text}</li>;`
   works, as "itemmm" is a random parameter which I have passed, also how "itemmm.text" correctly displays the text, as per my understanding "itemmm" is a vague object and I have not defined it anywhere.

**2)** Importance of `<TodoItems entries={this.state.items} />` line of code in my "TodoList.js" component. so far I understand it is using props to dynamically enter a value. But how is it tinkering with the TodoItem.js component?

Thank you for reading,sorry if its a too basic question. Any help would be much appreaciated.

Answer (score 1):

1.understanding "itemmm" is a vague object

```
createTasks(itemmm) {
    return <li key={itemmm.key}>{itemmm.text}</li>;
  }
```

Edit: regarding `key` and `text`

```
var newItem = {
        text: this._inputElement.value,
        key: Date.now()
      };

      this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
          items: prevState.items.concat(newItem)
        };
      });
```

The logic starts from here.

You get `items` as `[{key:23213123, text:'xyz'}]`

```
var listItems = this.props.entries.map(this.createTasks);
```

Here `itemmm` is the parameter and you can define it with any Name.

2. Items are passed into `TodoItems` to `entries` as props.

Comment: Regarding the 1st point, yes its true we a pass any name, But how is it accessing itemmm.text? it is not an object that I have defined. I have an object named "items"

Answer (score 0):

Abhinav you are passing items as props in entries and when you do map on an array there is a callback function which is createTask.

```
createTasks(itemmm) {
    return <li key={itemmm.key}>{itemmm.text}</li>;
 }
```

the above function is callback of map method of code below

```
this.props.entries.map(createTasks);
```

It is the same thing which i specify below.

```
this.props.entries.map((itemmm)=>{
  return <li key={itemmm.key}>{itemmm.text}</li>;
});
```

Comment: How itemmm.text is working? I have not defined the object